# Synthesis of 2-phenoxybutanal from but-1-yne

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, synthesis

[image: Reaction scheme]

How can I convert 1-butyne to 2-phenoxybutanal as shown above? I thought of using a hydroboration-oxidation sequence to introduce the carbonyl group, but I do not know how to add the phenoxy substituent.

Comment: Do you have any ideas about how you might accomplish the transformation, you could [edit] your post to include these so that people may help you more easily (if they know what exactly you're getting stuck at).  Also, welcome!  You might find the [tour] useful to learn more about chem.SE and how the stack exchange format works.

Comment: @AshleyAustin Consider using phenol for your addition instead of benzene. Also your product is 2-phenoxy-butanone (not phenyl).

Comment: How would I remove the H of the phenol group then?

Comment: So adding say h2o and phenol and the br- would work?

Comment: Phenol is a pretty decent nucleophile

Comment: Do you think you know how to do this reaction if it were an alkene instead?

Answer (score 2):

1. Water, BH3, H2O2, NaOH

This reaction, an hydroboration, yelds butanal

2. Br2, H2SO4

This reaction, carried without light, is an alpha carbon bromination, and yelds 2-bromobutanal

3. Sodium phenoxide

This is a simple Williamson Ether Synthesis, which yelds the final product

Comment: The edited question was wrong, and was not the OP's original question. The target compound was an aldehyde and not a ketone. I have changed it back to what it was supposed to be. Of course, this simply means that you just need to take out steps 2 and 3. (However it would also be appreciated if you could add some elaboration as to why you chose this sequence of events.)

Comment: I'm sorry, the question I answered explicited the request of reagents, without pointing out the reactions (the review " edited Jun 12 at 4:24 by Pritt Balagopal"), and the molecule in that review was a ketone.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would do:
[image]

I made the alkene symmetrical so that it would lead to fewer regioselective problems. However, I would advise starting with another starting material as this synthesis might take too long in practice.

Comment: The edited question was wrong, and was not the OP's original question. The target compound was an aldehyde and not a ketone. I have changed it back to what it was supposed to be.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend updating your answer to reflect that, or else it's technically not an answer.